# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\aino\aset\detil_barang.php on line 135

Tags: php

Please help me find error in the end of file from this below

```
<?php
      include('header.php');
      include "config/koneksi.php";

      function format_angka($angka){
      $frmt=number_format($angka,2,',','.');
      return $frmt;
      }`enter code here`
      ?>
            <div id="content">
                <!-- .outer -->
                <div class="container-fluid outer">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <!-- .inner -->
                        <div class="span12 inner">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span12">
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <header>
                                            <div class="icons"><i class="icon-edit icon-large"></i></div>
                                            <h5>Detail Aset</h5>
                                        </header>
                                        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in body">
                                            <ul class="breadcrumb">
                                                <li><a href="menu.php">Home</a> <span class="divider"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></span></li>
                                                <?php
                                                if($_GET['kat']=='null'){
                                                ?>
                                                <li><a href="tampil_aset.php">List Data</a> <span class="divider"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></span></li>
                                                <?php
                                                }else{
                                                ?>
                                                <li><a href="tampil_kategori.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']?>">List Data</a> <span class="divider"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></span></li>
                                                <?
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                                <li class="active">Detail</li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <?php 
                                            $idbarang=$_GET['id'];
                                            $idbarang = $_GET['id'];
                                            $tampil = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM barang WHERE id_barang ='$idbarang'") or die("gagal melakukan query") ;
                                            $data = mysql_fetch_array($tampil);
                                            ?>
                                                <div class="accordion-group">
                                                <table class="tableluar" name=dataaset cellpadding="5">
                                                <tr>
                                                <td width="20%">Nama Aset </td>
                                                <td> : </td>
                                                <td> <?php echo $data['nama_barang'];?> </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Detail Aset </td>
                                                <td> : </td>
                                                <td> <?php echo $data['detil_barang'];?> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            **Please finded**   
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Nomor Aset </td>
                                                <td> : </td>
                                                <td> <?php echo $data['id_aset'];?> </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Kategori </td>
                                                <td> : </td>
                                                <td><?php
                                                    switch($data['id_kategori']){
                                                        case 1 : echo ("Hardware");
                                                                break;
                                                        case 2 : echo ("Software");
                                                                break;
                                                        case 3 : echo ("Peralatan Kantor");
                                                                break;
                                                        case 4 : echo ("Bangunan");
                                                                break;
                                                        case 5 : echo ("Kendaraan");
                                                                break;
                                                    }?> 
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Tanggal perolehan </td>
                                                <td> : </td>
                                                <td> <?php echo $data['tanggal_pengadaan'];?> </td>
                                                </tr>
```

I want to solved problem in parse error

```
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Harga Perolehan </td>
                                                <td> : </td>
                                                <td> <?php echo "Rp ".format_angka($data['harga_perolehan']);?> </td>
                                                </tr>


                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Status </td>
                                                <td> : </td>
                                                <td> <?php echo $data['status'];?> </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Tanggal Status </td>
                                                <td> : </td>
                                                <td> <?php echo $data['tanggal_status'];?> </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                <td>PIC </td>
                                                <td> : </td>
                                                <td> <?php echo $data['p_i_c'];?> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <br>
                                                <center>
                                                <a href="update.php?id_kat=<?php echo $data['id_kategori'];?>&&id=<?php echo $data['id_barang']; ?>" title='Edit Data'><button class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon icon-edit"></i> Ubah</button></a>
                                                <a href="aksiForm.php?act=hapus&id=<?php echo $data['id_barang']; ?>" target="_self" alt="Delete Data" onClick="return  confirm('Anda yakin akan menghapus data?')"><button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon icon-trash"></i> Delete</button></a>
                                                </center>
                                                </div> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row-fluid -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.outer -->
            </div>
```

i want to find this error in here

error in here

I 've been many times trying to find errors in the code suffix , but still not met and still error , please help to look for errors on the same at the end of file

Comment: sorry my first time asking in stackoverflow so I gave the code still random mess , so I will move my code in pastebin http://pastebin.com/5UNA6tRw

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: so what should I do to get rid of the error message?

Comment: learn how to debug code. unexpected end = you forgot a `}` or something else, and left php dangling.